# Xcode - Malloc_Error in Release and Distribution configuration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I got this error only if I select Release or Distribution configuration on Device, on the Simulator it works well... please, where I mistake?

```
cc1obj(4113) malloc: *** mmap(size=429379584) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

cc1obj: out of memory allocating 429376832 bytes after a total of 0 bytes
{standard input}:13160:non-relocatable subtraction expression,
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Are you trying to load an enormous file or something? Over 400 MB?

Comment: I don't have any file of this size! O_O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because your simulator is able to allocate ~500Mb of memory while your iPhone is not able to do it. I think you should rethink what you are doing

- do you really need so much memory?
- isn't it just a calculating bug? (maybe a wrong `sizeof` or whatever)
- in any case this is really too much data to be handled

Comment: I don't understand why in Debug configuration and in Simulator it works..only on Device in Release/Distribution configuration I got this error

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to allocate 429 MB. iPhones don't have that much RAM. I suggest you look at what you're allocating to see why it's so big.

Comment: I don't have any file of this size, infact in Debug mode and in Simulator it works well..

Comment: Because the Simulator is software on your computer, and CAN allocate 500 MB. The Device is an iPhone and it does not have that much RAM. It would help if you would show us the line in your code that causes this problem. Also, it is not a file that is causing the problem. It is attempting to allocate this memory for something that is causing the problem. We know it is an allocation problem because of this: "out of memory allocating 429376832 bytes".

Comment: If I select Debug Configuration on device, it works well without any error or crash also on my iPhone 3G.. This happens only on Release/Distribution