# malloc: *** mmap(size=1048576) failed (error code=12) *** error: can't allocate region securely

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, crash

I have a app, when I had run it for a few minutes, it always crashed. I check the crash log, it always said
malloc: *** mmap(size=1048576) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region securely
I checked the memory leaks by using the instruments tools, but did not find any memory leak. I wonder if there are some memory leaks the instruments can not find, or some other reasons for the crash. 
any help will be appreciated!

**Edit:**

I used the time profiler to check the performance. but I don't know what's the key point because the top items are these:

Running Time    Self        Symbol Name
6494.0ms    9.4%    6494.0      -[DLStarView initWithDefault:highlighted:position:allowFractions:]
(my app has a lot of list, each item has a self made star view)

Running Time    Self        Symbol Name
5848.0ms    8.4%    5848.0      +[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] 
(my app always get data from sever)

Running Time    Self        Symbol Name
2169.0ms    3.1%    2169.0      -[BMKUserLocationInternal updateLocationInfo]

Running Time    Self        Symbol Name
1435.0ms    2.0%    1435.0      -[EGOCache imageForKey:]

Running Time    Self        Symbol Name
1252.0ms    1.8%    1252.0      -[KLRestDetailViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]

is it userful? how can I check if I stuffing a bunch of stuff?

PS: this crash only appear on the real device, I ran it in the simulator for about 20 minutes and the app still run smoothly, my device is iPhone4S iOS 6.0.1

I set a break point and got the messages:

the crash thread messages are not always the same
but in the console output, It always said 
malloc: *** mmap(size=1048576) failed (error code=12)**
 error: can't allocate region securely
** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I was so confused by this bug for a few days, any idea? thanks!

---

I used the time profiler to check the performance. but I don't know what's the key point because the top items are these:

Running Time    Self        Symbol Name
6494.0ms    9.4%    6494.0      -[DLStarView initWithDefault:highlighted:position:allowFractions:]
(my app has a lot of list, each item has a self made star view)

Running Time    Self        Symbol Name
5848.0ms    8.4%    5848.0      +[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] 
(my app always get data from sever)

Running Time    Self        Symbol Name
2169.0ms    3.1%    2169.0      -[BMKUserLocationInternal updateLocationInfo]

Running Time    Self        Symbol Name
1435.0ms    2.0%    1435.0      -[EGOCache imageForKey:]

Running Time    Self        Symbol Name
1252.0ms    1.8%    1252.0      -[KLRestDetailViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]

is it userful? how can I check if I stuffing a bunch of stuff?

PS: this crash only appear on the real device, I ran it in the simulator for about 20 minutes and the app still run smoothly, my device is iPhone4S iOS 6.0.1

I set a break point and got the messages:

libsystem_c.dylib`malloc_error_break:
0x33c742e8:  push   {r7, lr}
0x33c742ea:  mov    r7, sp
0x33c742ec:  nop 
0x33c742ee:  nop  
 
0x33c742f0:  pop    {r7, pc} 
0x33c742f2:  nop    
0x3393ed86:  movs   r2, #0 
0x3393ed88:  ldr    r0, [r0]
0x3393ed8a:  ldr    r0, [r4, r0]
0x3393ed8c:  blx    0x33aaf1c0; symbol stub for: -[NSUUID copyWithZone:]
0x3393ed90:  movw   r0, #52700
0x3393ed94:  movt   r0, #1571
0x3393ed98:  add    r0, pc
0x3393ed9a:  ldr    r1, [r0]

0x23ac72:  mov    r0, r5
0x23ac74:  str.w  r8, [sp]
0x23ac78:  blx    0x2c7d04                  ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x23ac7c:  b      0x23aca4                  ; -[BMKUserLocationInternal updateLocationInfo] 
+ 912 at BMKUserLocationInternal.mm:131
0x23ac7e:  bl     0x1cbcd8                  ; bmengine::GetGlobalMan() at 
IphoneBaiduMaps.mm:61

0x33941b7e:  mov    r0, r11
0x33941b80:  mov    r1, r8
0x33941b82:  mov    r2, r10
0x33941b84:  blx    0x33aace80                ; symbol stub for: CFDictionarySetValue$shim
0x33941b88:  movw   r0, #36884
0x33941b8c:  movt   r0, #1571
0x33941b90:  add    r0, pc
0x33941b92:  ldr    r4, [r0]
0x33941b94:  mov    r0, r11

0x23acd6:  movs   r3, #1
0x23acd8:  str    r3, [sp]
0x23acda:  movs   r3, #0
0x23acdc:  blx    0x2c7d04                  ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x23ace0:  add    sp, #4
0x23ace2:  pop    {r7, pc}

0x35bee92e:  ldr    r1, [sp, #224]
0x35bee930:  ldr    r2, [sp, #136]
0x35bee932:  ldr    r3, [sp, #232]
0x35bee934:  blx    0x35c268e4                ; symbol stub for: 
CLLocationDictionaryUtilitiesGetTransitionInterval
0x35bee938:  movw   r0, #1732
0x35bee93c:  movt   r0, #1078
0x35bee940:  add    r0, pc
0x35bee942:  ldr    r1, [r0]

the crash thread messages are not always the same
but in the console output, It always said 
malloc: *** mmap(size=1048576) failed (error code=12)**
 error: can't allocate region securely
** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I was so confused by this bug for a few days, any idea? thanks!

Comment: What did your memory usage look like? It's possible that you don't have any leaks, but that you're just holding on to a ton of memory that you don't need to. It's only a leak if there are no pointers in your app's address space pointing to it. But if you are, for example, stuffing a bunch of stuff into an `NSArray` that you'll never use again, technically that's not a leak because the array has a reference to it.

Comment: Run your app with the time profiler, figure out what methods are taking up most of the resources and paste the code so we can help

Comment: May be you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477236/malloc-error-cant-allocate-region-failed-with-error-code-12-any-idea-how-to