# can't allocate region malloc

Tags: ios

I am getting this error causing my app to crash:

```
..Splash-it(1369,0x5783000) malloc: *** mmap(size=516096) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I have no idea why the error is caused. Is it a memory problem error? How can I prevent it?
What do they mean by "set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug"?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: How much memory your application uses? On which device? Did you receive memory warning before this?

Comment: the new ipad, and no i didn't receive any memory worning

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477236/malloc-error-cant-allocate-region-failed-with-error-code-12-any-idea-how-to for some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i was getting this because imgCount is not getting value as my condition fails.
And the non void function is returning the value of imgCount.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(PSUICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger imgCount;
    if(collectionView == self.imageCollection) {
        imgCount=self.imageCount;
    }
    return imgCount;
}
```

So i resolved it by assigning the value to imgcount. 
It works for me.

Comment: This answer helped me by realizing i was just referencing a array for the count instead of array.count , thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that you are trying to allocate too much memory at once. I tried to malloc crazy big amounts of memory, and I got this error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but this is waht happened in my case & I resolved by **removing breakpoint**.

I was loading data from server & adding them to tableview & hiding or showing footer. At times my footer view was not appearing as I wanted so I inserted the breakpoints to check out whats going wrong. But then after some time doing the same activity my app got above error.

I tried this 2-3 times without breakpoint & it did not crash but, whenever I added breakpoint the error occured.

This may not be in your case but I guess if you are doing some large operations on main thread & if you have inserted breakpoints, you can atleast try this once.

Comment: By removing thebreakpoints you mean removing all by the-selecting the breackpoint button on the top bar? Is it ok if I leave them in the code itself?

Comment: I mean try to run your code by disabling breakpoint from you Xcode toolbar. See if it works.

Comment: I had them disabled even before, sorry